# Rearranging order of @dataProvider and database setup

Tags: phpunit, zend-db

So, Zend's phpunit database framework allows preloading a database with tables. However, this stops me from using @dataProvider with the database because it appears that @dataProvider gets executed before zend reloads the database. This causes the database tables to be out of sync.

Is there a way I can rearrange this procedure so that zend reloads the database, then @dataProvider gets called?

Answer (score 1):

When does Zend load your database? If you call it specifically from `setUp()` you could move the call to the data provider method. It's not ideal, but the way that PHPUnit calls the data providers is pretty core to its architecture. Sebastian is planning to rework this as some point, but I don't know how high it is on the priority list.

Edit: Sebastian created a ticket that discusses reordering tests based on `@depends`--not changing when data providers are called. My apologies for the confusion.

Comment: Zend extends the Database test case and overwrites this method:
`
    protected function getSetUpOperation()
    {
        return new PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_Operation_Composite(array(
            new Zend_Test_PHPUnit_Db_Operation_Truncate(),
            new Zend_Test_PHPUnit_Db_Operation_Insert(),
        ));
    }
`

Comment: @Ray H - That method is probably called from `setUp()` which means you're stuck. You could copy and modify Zend's test case class instead of extending it and have the data provider methods do the data setup. This is what I did for our Zend controller and view script tests as I needed more control and wanted to separate them.